# Spring boot - Embedded Tomcat - Connector Customizer - fail to add parseBodyMethods attributes

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7, embedded-tomcat-8

The original problem is when I sent a http request with method 'DELETE', the body part couldn't be sent to the server.

After googling, I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205062/requestbody-not-accepted-for-requestmethod-delete) that suggests modifying the server.xml file and adding 'parseBodyMethods' to the Connector part can solve the problem:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           parseBodyMethods="POST,PUT,DELETE"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

However, because I'm using spring's embedded tomcat, I have to find a way to do the same in spring's way. So, I found [this article](https://gist.github.com/SlyDen/9408539) that seems to allow me to add ConnectorCustomizer and add additional attribute to the Connector. The following is my code:

```
    public class MyTomcatConnectorCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {
        if(factory instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            customizeTomcat((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory);
        }
    }

    public void customizeTomcat(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory;
        tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
            connector.setAttribute("parseBodyMethods", "POST,PUT,DELETE");
        });
    }

}
```

---

```
@Bean
MyTomcatConnectorCustomizer myTomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
    MyTomcatConnectorCustomizer myTomcatConnectorCustomizer = new MyTomcatConnectorCustomizer();
    return myTomcatConnectorCustomizer;
}
```

But still, the same issue exists. the body is still empty when I send a 'DELETE' request to the server. Does anyone have encountered the same issue before? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
connector.setAttribute("parseBodyMethods", "POST,PUT,DELETE");
```

to

```
connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE")
```

or just

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
        @Override
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this is a bit old question but I stumbled upon this issue and found that SO don't have a solution for Spring Boot version 2.0.0 and later.

I had found [this](https://www.baeldung.com/embeddedservletcontainercustomizer-configurableembeddedservletcontainer-spring-boot) article on Baeldung which describes the changes in SB 2 versus SB 1.

Quoting the article (`code` emphasis is mine):

> In Spring Boot 2, the `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` interface is replaced by `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`, while the `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` class is replaced with `ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory`.

So to fix your issue you need to implement interface `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` from package `org.springframework.boot.web.server` and parametrize it with `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` and override it's `customize` method.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatConnectorCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyTomcatConnectorCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

  @Override
  public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
    TomcatConnectorCustomizer parseBodyMethodCustomizer = connector -> {
      connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
    };
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(parseBodyMethodCustomizer);
  }
}
```